# MATLAB/OpenCV: How to perform skeletal tracking on depth images?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, color-depth

I have a bunch of depth images (see below). I would like to perform skeletal tracking on them. This data is captured though ASUS Xtion sensor but I only have access to the depth images and not to the videos. Is there a straight forward way to perform skeletal tracking in MATLAB/OpenCV or something else on these depth images?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've used Asus Xtion and OpenNI to perform skeleton tracking, but that was with all the data. Not sure what results you will get. There's an example here so you should be able to test it fairly quickly: https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/tree/master/Samples/NiSimpleSkeleton

Comment: Thanks @reden I think Nite, openNI, g++ may need to be installed for this?

Comment: OpenNI definitely needed. I used prebuilt binaries (and Java), though